# Trying to make an image based whack-a-mole game in React with Codesandbox, but images won't change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm designing a game in Code Sandbox, Whack A Mole.  Basically, 9 images are on the screen.  Each one represents a hole.  One image is randomly chosen for the mole to pop up in.  When this happens, the src attribute of the image element is supposed to change.  Here's the code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import empty from "./hole.png";
import mole from "./mole.png";
import whacked from "./whacked.png";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [holeStates, setHoleStates] = useState([
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty },
    { hole: empty }
  ]);

  function start() {
    interval = window.setInterval(moveMole, 1000);
  }

  //why is "clear interval not working?"
  function stop() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  function moveMole() {
    //this should reset all holes back to empty, ensuring
    //two moles won't appear at once.

    for (x of holeStates) {
      x.hole = empty;
    }

    //this should give us a random number representing holes 1 - 9
    let randomHoleNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

    var copyArray = holeStates;

    copyArray[randomHoleNum] = { hole: mole };

    setHoleStates(copyArray);

    console.log(holeStates);
    //judging by the console log this seems to be working,
    //but the image doesn't change. Why?
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={stop}>Stop</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <img src={holeStates[0].hole} />
      <img src={holeStates[1].hole} />
      <img src={holeStates[2].hole} />
      <br />
      <img src={holeStates[3].hole} />
      <img src={holeStates[4].hole} />
      <img src={holeStates[5].hole} />
      <br />
      <img src={holeStates[6].hole} />
      <img src={holeStates[7].hole} />
      <img src={holeStates[8].hole} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is, even though it seems to be working based on the console log, the images on screen never change, at least not when they're supposed to.

What's going on?

From the console log I can see the properties of the objects do indeed change, just not the images on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you mutate the state.

> Arrays are mutable in JavaScript, but you should treat them as immutable when you store them in state. Just like with objects, when you want to update an array stored in state, you need to create a new one (or make a copy of an existing one), and then set state to use the new array.

Please see [updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays)

The working example:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import twitter from "./twitter.svg";
import instagram from "./instagram.svg";

let interval;
export default function App() {
    const [holeStates, setHoleStates] = useState([
        { hole: twitter },
        { hole: twitter },
        { hole: twitter },
        { hole: twitter },
        { hole: twitter },
        { hole: twitter },
        { hole: twitter },
        { hole: twitter },
        { hole: twitter },
    ]);

    function start() {
        interval = window.setInterval(moveMole, 1000);
    }

    function stop() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    function moveMole() {
        let randomHoleNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

        setHoleStates((pre) => {
            return pre.map((v, i) => {
                if (i === randomHoleNum) {
                    return { ...v, hole: instagram };
                }
                return { ...v, hole: twitter };
            });
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={stop}>Stop</button>
            <br />
            <br />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[0].hole} />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[1].hole} />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[2].hole} />
            <br />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[3].hole} />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[4].hole} />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[5].hole} />
            <br />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[6].hole} />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[7].hole} />
            <img width="16" src={holeStates[8].hole} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/77371128-nrxz69?file=/src/App.js:0-1405)

Comment: Well I'll be darned, that works!  I still don't really understand why.  I created 'copyArray' precisely so I could avoid "mutating the state".  I don't see how this isn't mutating the state but that was.  If you could explain that to me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @De2nis Make a [deep clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) of `holeStates` first, then mutate the cloned object, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Hmmm, alright, I still don't understand why "copyArray" doesn't count as a deep copy, though.    Seems like it should.